# On Pandas, how to drop multiple rows based in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Pandas and I am trying to drop all rows that contain some respective countries (Albania, Uzbekistan, Brazil) from the Column `country`. However, the way I figured it out to do is one by one, as below:

```
indexCountry = df[df['country'] == 'Albania'].index
df.drop(indexCountry, inplace = True)

indexCountry = df[df['country'] == 'Uzbekistan'].index
df.drop(indexCountry, inplace = True)

indexCountry = df[df['country'] == 'Brazil'].index
df.drop(indexCountry, inplace = True)
```

Is there a way to do this in one single code line, instead of having to do one for every country?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a filter like this:

```
df = df[~df["country"].isin(["Alabania", "Uzbekistan", "Brazil"])]
```

`~` is the negation of what it is followed by.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much @Yilun Zhang

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
list_of_countries = ['Albania',  'Uzbekistan', 'Brazil']
indexCountry = df[df['country'].isin(list_of_countries)].index 
df.drop(indexCountry, inplace = True)

or just:
list_of_countries = ['Albania',  'Uzbekistan', 'Brazil']
df[~df["country"].isin(list_of_countries)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this:

```
df = df[~df.country.str.contains('|'.join(["Albania","Uzbekistan","Brazil"]))]
```